# Tensorflow: sample of dataset gets shape None in map

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, data-augmentation

I have a dataset of spectrograms (images) of shape (128x128x1), I want to do dataaugmentation on it. But when I try to,

```
def augment(stft, label):                                           
    print(stft.shape)
    stft = tf.image.random_brightness(stft, 0.2)
    print(stft.shape)                                                                           
    stft = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shift(x=stft, wrg=0.1, hrg=0.1, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='wrap')
    return stft, label
    
val_ds= (
        val_ds.map(augment, num_parallel_calls=config.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(config.AUTOTUNE))
```

I get the following output and error:

```
(None, 128, 1)
(None, 128, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 132, in <module>
    val_ds.map(augment, num_parallel_calls=config.AUTOTUNE).prefetch(config.AUTOTUNE))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 1623, in map
    return ParallelMapDataset(
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 4016, in __init__
    self._map_func = StructuredFunctionWrapper(
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3221, in __init__
    self._function = wrapper_fn.get_concrete_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2531, in get_concrete_function
    graph_function = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2496, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2777, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2657, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 981, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3214, in wrapper_fn
    ret = _wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3156, in _wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 265, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
TypeError: in user code:

    train.py:128 augment  *
        stft = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shift(x=stft, wrg=0.1, hrg=0.1, row_axis=0, col_axis=1, channel_axis=2, fill_mode='wrap')
    /usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/affine_transformations.py:85 random_shift  *
        tx = np.random.uniform(-hrg, hrg) * h

    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Why is the shape of the tensor passed to the mapped function (None, 128, 1) and how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a batch size.

add

```
val_ds.batch(32)
```

before your map.